# Elegir solo un input radio de entre varios

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo esta serie de `input` tipo `radio`  en un formulario y quiero que de entre todos ellos sea posible elegir solo uno. Comparten una name que es de la que me estoy apoyando para poder referenciarlos, *Lo que quiero* es obtener el valor de checkbox checked por su name y sumar sus valores  , encontré que podía hacer esto en `JavaScript`:

```js
function calificacionCalc() {
  const np = $('#nPreguntas').val();
  var nt = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < np; i++) {
    let ni = i + 1;
    let getclass = "checkbox_" + ni;
    //hasta aquí todo buen mi get class = checkbox_1 por ejemplo
    let val = $(`input[name="${getclass}"]:checked`).val();
    //('input[name="locationthemes"]:checked')
    val = parseFloat(parseFloat);

    nt = nt + val;
    nt = parseFloat(nt);
  }
  alert(nt)


}
```

```html
<label class="checkbox-inline">
                                                                                        <input type="radio" name="checkbox_1" value="6"> 
Vivienda rentada  

</label>

<label class="checkbox-inline">
                                                                                        <input type="radio" name="checkbox_1" value="5"> 
Vivienda y  

</label>

<label class="checkbox-inline">
                                                                                        <input type="radio" name="checkbox_1" value="0"> 
Vivienda x  

</label>

<label class="checkbox-inline">
                                                                                        <input type="radio" name="checkbox_1" value="2"> 
Vivienda z  

</label>
```

El problema que tengo es que `val` me da `NaN`

Comment: Mencionas que tienes inputs radio pero usas checkbox, ¿Cuál vas a ocupar?

Comment: Justamente la función de un `input` de tipo `radio` es lograr que se pueda elegir solo uno de un _radio group_, pero en tu ejemplo estás utilizando `inputs` de tipo `checkbox`. Pero de todas maneras, intenta probar el _snippet_ con el código que has dejado de ejemplo, creo que hace lo que estás buscando, si no te funciona en tu entorno el problema debe estar en otro lado.

Comment: puedes colocar el resultado esperado? no logro compreder lo que deseas hacer

Comment: '  let val = $(`input[name="${getclass}"]:checked`).val(); ' con esto quiero obtener el valor del checkbox por name y dentro del script quiero sumar esos valores

Answer (score 1):

no se si te refieres a esto, pero por aquí te dejo el código, lo que he hecho ha sido cambiar el tipo a radio, y darle el mismo name a todos, ya que si tienen el mismo name no permite seleccionar varios a la vez.

```html
<div id="scoring_holder_ans1">
  <div>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="radio" class="checkbox_1" value="6" name="tipo">Vivienda propia 
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="radio" class="checkbox_1" value="5" name="tipo">
    Vivienda rentada  
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="radio" class="checkbox_1" value="4" name="tipo">
    Habita  en una casa propiedad de un familiar 
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="radio" class="checkbox_1" value="2" name="tipo">
    Vivienda prestada y compartida
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="radio" class="checkbox_1" value="0" name="tipo">
    Vivienda rentada, y compartida
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: actualizé la pregunta